How to set properties in a Spring Boot app from an external source
We want to populate the properties used in our Spring Boot app from an external source.
I tried using
@PropertySource(value = "file:\\C:\\app\\ConfFolder\\common.properties")


which works but is hard coded. I want to use a variable instead of C:\app\ConfFolder\common.properties. We want to run it via
java -DconfFile=C:\\app\\ConfFolder\\common.properties jar SampleApp.jar

How should we do it?

java -jar SampleApp.jar --spring.config.additional-location=file:C:\\app\\ConfFolder\\common.properties something along those lines (which is also explained in the reference guide.

Hello this method works fine if we have built a jar. But if I remove the @PropertySource then how will I build unless the properties also exist in application.properties file of the app

Ok thank you we can pass an extra argument while building
mvn clean install -Dspring.config.location=........

No not during building, during running.

use --spring.config.location= in the command line as specified in the below documentation.
http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html
other way you can do like :
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:default.properties")
    , @PropertySource(value = "file:${external.config}", ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
})

here specify a external.config in your application.properties.
This would provide a default path for overriding config, it will be overridable itself by specifying a --external.config in the command line.
